# Erlang: How to use a -define macro outside of a module?

Tags: erlang

Suppose I have the module test.erl, and inside it is the macro `TOTAL`:

```
-module(test)
-export([...])

-define(TOTAL,(100))

...
```

If `get_total()` was defined in test.erl, I could call `test:get_total().` from the REPL

How do I call `?TOTAL` (the macro) outside of the module test.erl without defining a function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could put the `-define` in a `test.hrl` file, and use `-include` to include that in other modules. See the [Erlang Preprocessor documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html) for more information.

### test.hrl

```
-define(TOTAL, (100)).
```

### test.erl

```
-module(test).
-export([...]).

-include("test.hrl").

...
```

### other.erl

```
-module(other).

-include("test.hrl").

io:format("TOTAL=~p~n", [?TOTAL]).
```

Comment: Not only "could" - that is how you "should" do it! ;)

Comment: Not what I was expecting, but this works very well and seems to be "best practice". Thanks!

Comment: Think C macros and you won't go far wrong, except not so many features.